# How to disable Swing button so I can change it by another button?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have Java Swing GUI, where I use 2 panels. The first panel holds buttons and these buttons represent Keys in Facility. The second panel is a control panel with some buttons and inputs.

And I need to do following: If I click on button in the first panel, it is disabled until I do some operation in the second panel or click it again. But obviously, if I click one button and then another one, the first one is not clicked anymore.

*Is there a way, how to disable the first button on click, keep it disabled and then proceed an operation to this button by clicking another button?*

Comment: Consider using a `JToggleButton` instead of a standard `JButton` .. For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: It start by defining some kind if model to manage and communicate the state, the it's just a matter of calling setEnabled with the required state

Answer (score 0):

Youu need to add and event handler in the second button

```
boolean status=true;

public void main
JButton btt = new JButton("button");
btt.setEnabled(status);

JButton btt2 = new JButton("button2");
btt2 .addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
        {
          status=!status;
          btt.setEnabled(status);

        }
}
```

This second button will toggle the first button status.